# Place a FAB in a Fragment

Tags: android, xml, fragment, floating-action-button

Good afternoon,

I am trying to put a FAB at the bottom|end of a fragment, but I do not know where I can place it.

Here is the Fragment's xml code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cars_list_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_layout">
                <include layout="@layout/write_comment"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the FAB :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
```

Thanks for your help !

An answer helped me to have a first "solution" with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/cars_list_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollable_layout">
                    <include layout="@layout/write_comment"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it does not work correctly :

[image]

Comment: see my answer bellow.

Comment: can you post updated  xml  code

Comment: Of course, I did it !

Comment: at my end it works fine I think there issue at AppBar layout or toolbar at FragmentActivity so post that code also.

Comment: The problem comes from the
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
in the Toolbar, when I remove this line the FAB works properly. But I need these toolbar properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/cars_list_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFabButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think that's the correct way, but what is :
tools:context="com.firstcry.warehouse.LandingActivity" ?

Thanks!

Comment: @D.Math  Sorry its my mistake, now check  updated answer.

Comment: @D.Math - He has simply added a parent layout of type `RelativeLayout`. This allows you to have control over a `View`'s position relative to other views. For example, the `Fab` has properties that state `alignParentBottom` and `alignParentLeft` - because the parent is a `RelativeLayout`, the `Fab` understands where the bottom is and where left is. Though, my only recommendation would be to put it to the right as that seems to be the norm.

Comment: Finally, it isn't working, the FAB is to low, we only can see the 30% of it before scrolling...

Comment: @Subby you are very correct but as per   D.Math  requirement so I  have code like that ,D.math Please think about suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Check below Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/contactnew">

    <include
        layout="@layout/contentcontact"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/facebookfab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#fff"
        android:src="@mipmap/facebook" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/callfab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/Color_Blue"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Check this layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/lawbook"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"

                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/aliyar"

                android:layout_above="@+id/text121"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="71dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image12"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/text121"
                android:text="@string/aliyar1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text121"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/aliyar2"
                android:id="@+id/text122"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text122"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/aliyar3"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/text123"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text123"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/aliyar4"
                android:id="@+id/text124"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text124"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/aliyar5"
                android:id="@+id/text125"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text125"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/aliyar6"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/text126"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                />




        </RelativeLayout>





    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```