# How to correctly align element at bottom inside a fragment

Tags: android

Following my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The FloatingActionButton is not correctly aligned at the bottom, but it is only partially visible, as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THRbS.jpg. I don't want the FloatingActionButton inside the activity_main. How to correctly align it at the bottom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place a FAB in a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995358/place-a-fab-in-a-fragment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottom Align Floating Action Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769080/bottom-align-floating-action-button)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    ...

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```